# Get all Paths between 2 Nodes in a simple graph using JGraphT

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht, longest-path

I' m currently studying the JGraphT libraries to manipulate Graphs in Java, in particular I'm trying to identify the longest path between 2 nodes in a simple graph and I know that I can get there by using a recursive method.
Anyway, I found in Java docs the AllDirectedGraphs library that can handle the job in case of directed graphs, here' s a simple example:

```java
//the nodes of the graph are countries and the edges are the routes that connect the countries by land

AllDirectedPaths<Country, DefaultEdge> paths = new AllDirectedPaths<Country, DefaultEdge(graph);

//getting all the paths between 2 random countries
         
List<GraphPath<Country, DefaultEdge>> longestPath = paths.getAllPaths(countries.get(220), countries.get(325), true, null);

GraphPath<Country, DefaultEdge> obj = null;
double maxlenght=0;
         
for( GraphPath<Country, DefaultEdge> pa :longestPath ) {
                     
         if(pa.getLength()>maxlenght)
             obj= pa;
        }
return obj;
}
```

Obviously using an undirected graph with the same method throw an Exception, so I' m wondering if there is a similar workaround with a simple graph, since I can' t find it by my self .

Comment: Currently, JGrapht does not contain an algorithm to compute the longest path between a pair of vertices in a simple graph. Similarly, there's no algorithm that computes all simple paths between a pair of vertices. A quick and dirty hack is to transform your undirected graph into a directed graph by representing every undirected edge (u,v) by two directed arcs {(u,v),(v,u)}. This approach is not particularly scalable. I'd recommend implementing a dedicated method to solve this problem.

Comment: Too bad that this "feature" is missing, thank you for the response